# Как сохранять написанное в нескольких QLineEdit и воспроизводить через QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit, qlistwidget

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сохранять значения из всех `lineEdit` чтобы потом вызывать их через список?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(658, 239)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 591, 133))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 658, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись2"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запись3"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Del"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.process)
 
    def process(self):
        vc1 = self.lineEdit
        vc2 = self.lineEdit_2
        ppc = [vc1, vc2] 
        lineEdits =  ppc
        text = ''
        num1 = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        num2 = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        s = num1 // num2
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(str(s))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать. У вас есть три QLineEdit в них может быть что-то написано. И вы хотите по нажатию на кнопку Save чтобы эти значения попали куда? И что такое включать их через список?

Comment: @S.Nick я хочу все что написано в трех QLineEdit сохранять и вызывать сохраненные значения через список

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что я заменил виджет `QListWidget` на `QTableWidget`и реализовал доя вас то что вы хотите.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(658, 239)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 591, 133))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)

# !!! tableWidget -----------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvv 
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3, self.gridLayoutWidget)     # !!! tableWidget
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 658, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Del"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.process)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.save_process)
        
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) 
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnHidden(1, True) 
        self.tableWidget.setColumnHidden(2, True)
        self.tableWidget.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self.double_clicked)
        
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def double_clicked(self, row, column): 
        vc1 = self.tableWidget.item(row, 1).text()
        vc2 = self.tableWidget.item(row, 2).text()
        self.lineEdit.setText(vc1)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(vc2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(f'{int(vc1) // int(vc2)}')

    def save_process(self):
        vc1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        vc2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        if not vc1 or not vc2:
            return
        
        item = QTableWidgetItem(f'{vc1} // {vc2} = {int(vc1) // int(vc2)}')
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 0, item)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 1, QTableWidgetItem(vc1))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 2, QTableWidgetItem(vc2))
 
    def process(self):
        vc1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        vc2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        if not vc1 or not vc2:
            return

        self.lineEdit_3.setText(f'{int(vc1) // int(vc2)}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Kkrski что не так?